# How to close connection in @aspnet/signalr?

Tags: angular, angular8

I use dependency   `"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4".`

How to close connection in destructor Angular?

I have tried:

```
 this.connection.close();
```

Comment: Now when I go to another component I still get messages from socket in prev component

Comment: `this.connection.stop();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (this.connection) {
   this.connection.stop();
   this.connection= undefined;
}
```

Regards